# Waiting for sql query response in ios

Tags: ios, sql, xcode

I am using Xcode creating an iOS app. I am also using a SQL server (xampp). It works good overall. But I have problem at the following point:

-I have view controller with a Table View and I am populating this table using the result of the SQL query (imagine taglist is an array containing 12 rows)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad

[[API sharedInstance] commandWithParams:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"listtags", @"command", nil] onCompletion:^(NSDictionary *json) {

    NSArray* result = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[json objectForKey:@"result"]];
    taglist =[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:result];
    [taglist removeAllObjects];
    for(NSDictionary* i in result){
        [taglist addObject:[i objectForKey:@"tag"]];
    }
    NSLog(@"sql %u",taglist.count);
}];

NSLog(@"did load %u",taglist.count);
```

}

And there are two required methods for tableviews

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

NSLog(@"table %u",taglist.count);
return taglist.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


NSLog(@"cell %u",taglist.count);
cell.textLabel.text = [taglist objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
```

}

The problem is since it takes a while to get the query result, my table methods use the empty taglist array to populate. The output of the NSLogs are like this

```
2012-12-19 14:35:41.470 iReporter[33507:c07] did load 0
2012-12-19 14:35:41.473 iReporter[33507:c07] table 0
2012-12-19 14:35:41.476 iReporter[33507:c07] cell 0
2012-12-19 14:35:41.479 iReporter[33507:c07] cell 0
2012-12-19 14:35:41.481 iReporter[33507:c07] cell 0
2012-12-19 14:35:41.483 iReporter[33507:c07] cell 0
2012-12-19 14:35:41.484 iReporter[33507:c07] cell 0
2012-12-19 14:35:41.486 iReporter[33507:c07] cell 0
2012-12-19 14:35:41.487 iReporter[33507:c07] cell 0
2012-12-19 14:35:41.489 iReporter[33507:c07] cell 0
2012-12-19 14:35:41.493 iReporter[33507:c07] cell 0
2012-12-19 14:35:41.564 iReporter[33507:c07] sql 12
```

Which means the taglist array is empty after the viewDidload , numberofRows and cellForRow functions. But when the query is completed I can get the correct value. But by then my table properties are already defined so it is no use,
My question is , is there a way to wait for that response and after making sure that it is not empty then to use it to create the table. 
Thank you

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this? I have a very similar problem.

Comment: Its been so long but below answer should work. Anything inside the block is performed after the query is completed.

onCompletion:^(NSDictionary *json) {

 //
[self.tableView reloadData]
}];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you get the results from your query and you update `taglist`, call `[self.tableView reloadData]`.

Comment: Hi, how can you know for sure when they query he's performing on viewDidLoad is finished? I have a similar situation.  Can it be put in some block or something similar?